# WCF over Http and Https resolving local address in WSDL

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, https, wsdl

Recently we added HTTPS to one of our WCF services that is exposed over REST and SOAP endpoints.

When we made this modification, the SOAP endpoints are experiencing issues that I am unable to find fixes for.

The problem I am having right now is that when the HTTP endpoint is consumed, the SOAP address given in the WSDL is pointing to the local address. This is not allowing the service to be consumed over HTTP and only of HTTPS.

The web.config is the following for the relevant section:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttpsBinding">
      <security mode="Transport"/>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior"
           name="Some.Path.To.MyService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="basicHttpsBinding"
              contract="Some.Path.To.IMyService"/>
  <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="PingPostServiceBehavior">
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentInstances="800"
                         maxConcurrentCalls="800"
                         maxConcurrentSessions="800"/>
      <!--<useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress/>-->
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
```

When I go to the PRODUCTION HTTP WSDL address, the local address is given in the soap address element as shown in following image. I apologize about the bad censor job.

[image]

Comment: Does this setting help? http://ajitapi.blogspot.com/2010/07/configuring-wcf-service-work-behind.html

Comment: I am looking into this, but I also want to mention that when I pull up the WSDL when running the service locally, it happens as well instead of using the address that I have specified in the IIS host header.